# Merging tables from different sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 different Sub declarations that all pretty much do the same thing. The only part that differs are the the worksheet variants (each Sub uses 2 specific worksheets).

What I'm trying to do is condense the 5 different Subs into one piece.

The below code is an example of one of my Subs (note the code below is only change throughout the Subs)

**Only code that changes in the below group1 Sub.**

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("A")
Set addWS = wb.Worksheets("A add")
```

**Code for one of the Subs**

```
   ' -- Combines table1 and table2 -- '
    Sub group1()
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim addWS As Worksheet
        Dim counter As Long
        Dim counterAdd As Long 'counter for additional trades

        Set wb = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm")
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("A")
        Set addWS = wb.Worksheets("A add")

        ws.Activate 'activate sheet

        ' Checks to see if there is only 1 row or is empty
        If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A11").Value) = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A12").Value) = True And IsEmpty(ws.Range("A11").Value) = False Then
            counter = 1
        Else
            counter = ws.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.count
        End If


        addWS.Activate 'activate additional sheet

        ' Checks to see if there is only 1 row or is empty
        If IsEmpty(addWS.Range("A11").Value) = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If IsEmpty(addWS.Range("A12").Value) = True And IsEmpty(addWS.Range("A11").Value) = False Then
            counterAdd = 1
        Else
            counterAdd = addWS.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.count
        End If


        ' Copy / paste additional trades
        addWS.Range("A11:AB" & counterAdd + 10).Copy

        ws.Activate
        ws.Range("A" & counter + 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End Sub
```

**In the below code I attempted to make this into one Sub with with 2 For loops, however it would get stuck in the second loop. Is there a way that I could loop through two things at once?**

```
   ' -- Combines table1 and table2 -- '
    Sub group()
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim wsAdd As Worksheet
        Dim counter As Long
        Dim counterAdd As Long 'counter for additional trades
        Dim WSArray As Variant
        Dim WSArrayAdd As Variant

        Set wb = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm")

        WSArray = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
        WSArrayAdd = Array("A add", "B add", "C add", "D add", "E add")

        'Loop through WSArray sheets
        For Each currentWS In WSArray
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(currentWS)
            ws.Activate

            ' Checks to see if there is only 1 row or is empty
            If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A11").Value) = True Then
                ' do nothing
            End If

            If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A12").Value) = True And IsEmpty(ws.Range("A11").Value) = False Then
                counter = 1
            Else
                counter = ws.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.count
            End If

            For Each currentAddWS In WSArrayAdd
                Set wsAdd = wb.Worksheets(currentAddWS)
                wsAdd.Activate 'activate additional sheet

                ' Checks to see if there is only 1 row or is empty
                If IsEmpty(wsAdd.Range("A11").Value) = True Then
                    ' do nothing
                End If

                If IsEmpty(wsAdd.Range("A12").Value) = True And IsEmpty(wsAdd.Range("A11").Value) = False Then
                    counterAdd = 1
                Else
                    counterAdd = wsAdd.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.count
                End If


                ' Copy / paste additional trades
                wsAdd.Range("A11:AB" & counterAdd + 10).Copy

                ws.Activate
                ws.Range("A" & counter + 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Next currentAddWS
        Next currentWS

    End Sub
```

Comment: You only need to loop through `WSArray`, when the time come to name the second sheet you can use `Set addWS = wb.Worksheets(WSArray(i) & " add")` (where `i` the the counter used to loop through the array)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks for the help! I was able to solve this in my code below!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in the code below. This code loops through a series of 10 sheets (each sheet has a corresponding sheet) and combines the tables to one main sheet.

```
' -- Combines additional trades table with main table -- '
Sub groupTables()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsAdd As Worksheet
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim counterAdd As Long 'counter for additional trades
    Dim WSArray As Variant
    Dim WSArrayAdd As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm")

    WSArray = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

    'Loop through WSArray sheets
    For Each currentWS In WSArray
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(currentWS)
        Set wsAdd = wb.Worksheets(WSArray(i) & " add")

        ws.Activate

        ' COUNTS ROWS IN TRADE SHEET
        ' Checks to see if there is only 1 row or is empty
        If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A11").Value) = True Then
            counter = 0  'no trades
        ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Range("A12").Value) = True And IsEmpty(ws.Range("A11").Value) = False Then
            counter = 1
        Else
            counter = ws.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.count
        End If

        wsAdd.Activate

        ' COUNTS ROWS IN ADDITIONAL TRADE SHEET
        ' Checks to see if there is only 1 row or is empty
        If IsEmpty(wsAdd.Range("A11").Value) = True Then
            counterAdd = 0  'no trades
        ElseIf IsEmpty(wsAdd.Range("A12").Value) = True And IsEmpty(wsAdd.Range("A11").Value) = False Then
            counterAdd = 1
        Else
            counterAdd = wsAdd.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.count
        End If

        'Copy Additional trades
        If counterAdd > 0 Then
            wsAdd.Range("A11:AB" & counterAdd + 10).Copy    'Copy additional trades table
            ws.Activate
            ws.Range("A" & counter + 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll ' Paste additional trades to main table
        End If

        i = i + 1   'iterate

    Next currentWS

End Sub
```